# jqGrid Column Value Empties When Editing Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.4.4. I have a column in jqGrid as follows:

```
 { key: false, name: 'RUN_DT', index: 'RUN_DT', editable: false, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' }, formoptions: {}, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validDateCheck } },
```

When I do an inline row edit and save, the value that is in this column is erased. How can I prevent the data in this column from erasing when editing other columns in the row?

Comment: It sounds very strange. Either the code of `validDateCheck` or the usage of inline editing is wrong or it's a bug in the old 4.4.4 version which you use. Can you provide the demo which reproduces the problem? Do you verified that after changing jqGrid URLs from 4.4.4 to free jqGrid 4.13.3 you have the same problem? The test with another version of jqGrid is very practical to localize the origin of the problem: either the origing is in your code or in jqGrid version, which you use.

Comment: I've tried both with and without the validDateCheck function, and I get the same result. When I enable editing, I don't have the problem.

Comment: If you provide the demo which uses 4.13.3 and have the described problem I would analyse/debug it and will try to fix it. In any way I have to be able to reproduce and to debug the problem which you report. If the problem is the bug in 4.4.4, then I will probably can't help you. The text of your current question don't contains enough details that other can reproduce the problem and help you.

Comment: It's difficult to provide a demo, because the grid uses calls to controller actions in ASP.NET MVC. I tried it with free jqGrid, but I ran into other issues just trying to get it to work at all. My controller action result takes an entity framework object as a parameter, so I'm assuming that jqGrid is only passing the values that are defaulted or entered rather than those that are populated in the grid from the db. I've found a workaround by having editable: true and it gets passed to the entity framework object.

Comment: Free jqGrid support other values as `true` and `false` for the property `editable`. One can use `"hidden"`, `"disabled"`, `"readonly"` additionally to `true` and `false` and the value of the property `editable` could be the function, which returns one from the value. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for more details. About the problems with creating the demo. You current question contains almost no JavaScript code and you use even `editable: false`. Nobody can help you having so small information about the problem.